# How to retrieve user's Private Key from Active Directory with C# (=How to get a PKCS12 (PFX) certificate from Active Directory?)

Tags: c#, active-directory, pki

We are implementing a digital signature ad-hoc scheme using Active Directy and C#.
We would like to know how should we proceed to RETRIEVE the Private Key (or the user's PFX file) from the user's account entry on the AD, so that we can use that private key to sign some information.  At the same, how to properly install the PFX file for each user in AD ? (so that we can retrieve it later programatically)

We are already accessing the AD and retrieving the Public Key information from the field "userCert", which we are now using to verify signed documents, but we need to access the private key to sign those documents first !

We are using LDAP to access AD.  Something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry o2ADEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://darwin.charles/DC=domain, DC=info", "user", "password");
DirectorySearcher o2objSearch = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(o2ADEntry);

o2objSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
o2objSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
o2objSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userCert");
o2objSearch.Filter = (string.Format("(samaccountname={0})", "user")); 

SearchResult res = o2objSearch.FindOne();
if (res != null)
{
   CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:name", NamespaceManager).SetValue(res.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString());
   FormState["certificate"] = res.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["userCert"].Value;
}
```

We are also using standard Microsoft Crypto API (no bouncycastle, no OpenSSL.NET).

We checked here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996408(v=exchg.65).aspx, but nothing is said about how to access the privatekey.

Thanks a lot, friends !

Comment: The private key should be stored on the smartcard and not in a public place? The certiticate field contains the public key.

Comment: Michael-O thanks !  We are trying to implement something cheaper without smartcards but using AD as a PKCS #12 repository or something like this (otherwise we must store all the pfx files in a server file system).  Do you think that AD can't be used to something like this ?  Thanks again.

Comment: You could create/store custom attributes on each account object, but you have to secure those attributes. Private keys are private for a reason.

Comment: @faturita, what are you trying to do? Soft PKI? Private key on disk just like with SSH PKI?

Comment: @Michael-O I would rather say: "Cheap PKI", without smartcards.  If you can store the PKCS12, with the PKI, inside the Active Directory, that will be better than the FileSystem.  Any hint ?

Comment: @faturita, this is soft PKI (PKI without smartcards), private key is stored on disk or USB drive. Is there a reason why you do not want to use standard smartdard mechs?

Comment: Thanks Jake ! The idea is that Private Keys will be password protected by the PKCS#12 spec.

Comment: @Michael-O yes! they are expensive and very difficult to import...

Comment: @faturita, going back to the topic. The way you want to do taht is impossible. The client wields the private certificate not the AD. The AD contains the public cert only. Rethink your problem or approach.